# Given a fonts.googleapis.com link, locally cache the font collection

Tags: fonts, google-font-api, google-webfonts

Doing this with the [google fonts browser](https://www.google.com/fonts) seems daunting. I have this link, which is working for my site:

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700
```

Now, I am doing offline development, and I just want to have those fonts locally cached. According to the [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/fonts/faq?hl=en) I need to start selecting fonts here and there, until I feel I have selected what I want, and then download the collection. That is just not gonna fly, Jim.

Is there an easy way, *given the original link*, to download the whole collection?

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about the first FAQ entry, right? Well, that's right but only explains how to download the font file. That does not mean you can use it right away in your web page, because there is more behind the scenes Google does not mention.

First, there are 5 different font formats supported by Google Fonts, which are WOFF, WOFF2, TTF, EOT and SVG. All these formats are required by different browsers - because it would just be too simple if those guys could align for once and use the same format... anyway, you are not able to download all these formats from Google. Only TTF is directly downloadable. Furthermore, the CSS behind the link you posted is generated dynamically and depends on the user agent. This makes sure every browser gets the font format it supports.

That makes it quite hard to cache the whole thing locally and keeping support for all browsers - since you're developing locally (with no internet connection that means, I guess) you probably will test in different browser all the time. Luckily there are some helpers. My favorite is http://www.localfont.com/ - you simply select the font and you will get all font formats including a cross browser CSS declaration for download.